# Install newer version of chart side by side

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to implement canary deployment with Istio but first I have to deploy chart pods from the old version (Already managed to do it) and chart pods from the new version.
I created a new version of my chart. The chart has been created successfully.
Now I try to use `helm install` command to deploy the new version side by side with the old one.
I pass a new release name to the command in order to avoid overriding the old version `my-release-v2` but I get an error that the `release name in the chart must match the release name`.
At this stage I'm a bit puzzled. Should I override it in the `values.yaml` if so - How exactly? Is this a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this one is case it helps someone.
The release name should be unique. A good practice is to use our application name `Chart.AppName.fullname` along with the intended version in our `helm install` conmmand.
Then, we can use the same practice for our `Deployment` object that deploys our pods so it will be unique to the version. (Relevant part in the `deployment.yaml`)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include ".Chart.Name.fullname" . }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
```

And of course for a future selector in `Istio` create a version label in the pods (Relevant part in the `deployment.yaml`):

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
```